# UINavigationController modalPresentationStyle not working on iPhones

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle

I'm trying to present UINavigationController as a small window using the following way. It works fine on iPads but it still displays fullScreen on iPhones. Any tips on what I am doing wrong will be greatly appreciated!

```
class LoginNewNavigationController: UINavigationController{
    
    private var windowSize: CGSize!
    
    init() {
        let rootVc = LoginNewIPadViewController.init()
        super.init(rootViewController: rootVc)
        
        self.configureSizes()
        self.preferredContentSize = self.windowSize
        self.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
        self.showNavigationBar = false
        self.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A "smaller window" presentation is not built in on iPhone. You need a custom presentation controller that dictates a smaller size and placement of the presented view controller.

Comment: I want to present UINavigationController as a small window.

Comment: Then you don't want a form sheet. You need a custom presentation controller.

Comment: See my https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7 for an example of how to write such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

It's the LoginnewIPadViewController that needs to have it's modal presentation style set not the navigation controller. Also there is no need to reference self the scope is clear for the compiler.

```
class LoginNewNavigationController: UINavigationController{

private var windowSize: CGSize!

    init() {
        let rootVc = LoginNewIPadViewController.init()
        rootVc.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
        super.init(rootViewController: rootVc)
        configureSizes()
        preferredContentSize = windowSize
        showNavigationBar = false
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to present UINavigationController as a small window. This one not works.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with a `formSheet` on iPhone, it can be achieved using `.popover` style. See following example -

```
class LoginNewIPadViewController: UIViewController {}

class LoginNewNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    
    private var windowSize: CGSize!
    
    init() {
        let rootVC = LoginNewIPadViewController.init()
        super.init(rootViewController: rootVC)
        
        self.preferredContentSize = self.windowSize
        self.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        
        if let presentationController = self.popoverPresentationController {
            /// Configure the way you want this to be shown
            // presentationController.sourceRect = ??
            // presentationController.sourceView = ??
            // presentationController.barButtonItem = ??
            presentationController.permittedArrowDirections = .up
            presentationController.delegate = self
        }
    }
    
}

extension LoginNewNavigationController: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {
    func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return .none
    }
}
```